# How to debug the "dis" module

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, pdb

I am trying to debug the "dis" module coming with Python 3.7, just want to follow its execution and scope some data structure.

Following this [simple guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChuU3NlYRLQ), I did this:

1. Insert "`import pdb`" at the top of the file
2. Insert "`pdb.set_trace()`" at the start of "`disassemble`" function

The target code is just oneliner: `print("hello")`

Then I build python source, but I got an error:

```
python ImportError: cannot import name 'CO_GENERATOR' from 'inspect'
```

Then I go to the source directory and run "`python3.7 dis.py`", there is no error, but pdb does not come up either. I guess it is waiting for file name?

Guess I am not on the right direction. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "Then I build python source"?

Comment: Assuming you have it, try running `type -P python3.7`, then `ldd FULLPATHTOPYTHON3.7`. There is a decent chance you're dynamic linking an older `libpython.so` (and as a consequence, not really running Python 3.7) while trying to analyze `dis.py` from Python 3.7.